# Kerberos client usage in windows

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I have installed Kerberos of MIT from this setup:
http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/kfw/2.6/kfw-2.6.5/MITKerberosForWindows-2.6.5.exe

I couldnt create realm as I did using 'krb5_newrealm' commanf in ubuntu. I used the following guide for Kerberos setup in Linux. http://blog.manula.org/2012/04/setting-up-kerberos-server-with-debian.html

But my need is to set Kerberos in windows machine(version 8.1).

Please guide, where I have to check the same.

Comment: I could find that Kerberos can be mode worked only If Active Directory is installed in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Kerberos client in windows machine even if Active Directory is is not installed.

You can refer "Appendix A: Configuring Kerberos Authentication for Windows" from below user guide for step by step Configuration of Kerberos Setup.

http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Product-Guide-HDP-2.1-v1.01.pdf

Comment: @Praveen, I could follow the installation steps mentioned in the user guide. But no realm is displayed in Ticket Manager , though I restart my system.

Comment: After you open MIT Kerberos Ticket Manager are you able to say GET Ticket and authenticate your principal properly??

Comment: No; Because No realm is present in the window; I think Get Ticket is possible only if there is any default realm;